# c# Add to list null reference (instance of list exists)

Tags: c#, list

Im trying to add objects called Process to the list. It returns a null reference exception when I try to add items to the list. (lijst.Add)

I search the net and find mostly answers like: you dont have instantiated the list. Well here it is instantiated so what could be wrong with this code? All other variables are filled correctly.

This is the code:

```
private List<Process> CreateProcessFromXml()
    { 
        List<Process> lijst = new List<Process>();

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "Process.xml");
        XDocument process = XDocument.Load(path);
        var elementen = XElement.Load(path);
        foreach (var element in elementen.Elements("Proces"))
        {
            lijst.Add(
                new Process
                {
                    Naam = element.Element("Naam").Value,
                    TemplatePath = element.Element("TemplatePath").Value,
                    OutputPath = element.Element("OutPutPath").Value,
                    OutputDocumentName = element.Element("OutputDocumentName").Value
                });
        }
        return lijst;
    }
```

Process class:

```
public class Process
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string TemplatePath { get; set; }
    public string OutputPath { get; set; }
    public string OutputDocumentName { get; set; }
}
```

Exception tekst:

Line 34:             foreach (var element in elementen.Elements("Proces"))

Line 35:             {

Line 36:                 **lijst.Add(new Process** (in red)

Line 37:                 {

Line 38:                     Naam = element.Element("Naam").Value,

Source File: xxxxxxxx    Line: 36

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

```
XML: <Proces>
    <Naam>
    </Naam>
    <TemplatePath>
    </TemplatePath>
    <OutputPath>
    </OutputPath>
    <OutputDocumentName>
    </OutputDocumentName>
  </Proces>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `list.Add()` throws that exception and not one of your `element.Element(...)`?

Comment: Process is just something i created myself. The elements are filled with XML contents!

Comment: Debug your code, see exactly what row throws the exception. My guess is that one of the xml elements is missing somewhere.

Comment: What does the stack-trace of that exception tell you? I suspect one of the `Element("...")` calls returns `null`.

Comment: I updated my question thanks guys.

Comment: Stupid typo I made while searching in the XML file OutputPath its named! The XML node value somewhere is null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is instantiated and `List.Add()` will work fine. The problem is here:

```
new Process
{
    Naam = element.Element("Naam").Value,
    TemplatePath = element.Element("TemplatePath").Value,
    OutputPath = element.Element("OutPutPath").Value,
    OutputDocumentName = element.Element("OutputDocumentName").Value
});
```

Check every line of this code to be sure all operations return expected results.

Comment: Hey thanks, I misspelled OutPutPath should have been OutputPath. Why does the stacktrace/exception info does not tell me anything about that value but instead points me to list.add as point where the exception occured?

Comment: @TerryvandenBerg, it is because you create object inside Add() method. You can see Usman answer - if you create process object outside Add() method the exception will occur in line with OutputPath.

Answer (score 3):

a better way to trace the error is

```
foreach (var element in elementen.Elements("Proces"))
        {
            Process process = new Process();


             process.Naam = element.Element("Naam").Value;
             process.TemplatePath = element.Element("TemplatePath").Value;
             process.OutputPath = element.Element("OutPutPath").Value;
             process.OutputDocumentName = element.Element("OutputDocumentName").Value;
             lijst.Add(process)
        }
```

and add a break point to check the code line by line